# Prove if $F \subset E$ is a finite dimensional field extension then $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$ is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra

My idea is that since $F \subset E$ is finite dimensional then the set of roots (call it $R$) of $E$ is finite so $\operatorname{Sym}(R)$ is finite and since the Galois group can be embedded in the symmetric group, $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$ must be finite, but I'm struggling with the details.

Comment: Let $a_1,...,a_m$ be a basis of $E$ over $F$. Let $a_1,...,a_n$, be that basis together with all their conjugates. It is a finite collection because each $a_i$, $i\leq m$ is algebraic over $F$. An element of $\sigma\in Gal(E/F)$ fixes $\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x-a_k)$, because this is a polynomial in $F[x]$. Therefore $a_1,..,a_m$ are sent to elements of $a_1,...,a_n$. Moreover, since $\sigma$ is $F$-linear, it is determined as soon as you give its values at $a_1,...,a_m$.

Comment: That's the right approach. All that's left to show is that the galois group can actually be embedded in a symmetric group. What should the map be?

Comment: @leibnewtz we have a theorem in our notes that says "If $F \subset E, f \in F[x], R$ the set of of roots of $f$ in $E$ then if $E$ is generated by $R$ over $F$ the action of $Gal(E/F)$ on $R$, $\phi \in Gal(E/F) \rightarrow \phi |_R ] \in Sym(R)$ defines an embedding of $Gal(E/F)$ into $Sym(R)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Galois automorphism is determined by its restriction on the basis since it is linear. If $(e_1,...,e_n)$ is a basis, the image of $e_I$ is an element of the set $S_i$ of root of its minimal polynomial. Let  So the number of Galois automorphisms is finite since it has the cardinality of a subset of $S_1\times...\times S_n$.